# Operational Error with Inserting a Datetime attribute in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, datetime, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm receiving the following error, when I attempt to create an object with the datetime attribute:

*datebase_setup file:*

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
Base = declarative_base()
class User(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'user'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
   name = Column(String(200), nullable = False)
   email = Column(String(200), nullable = False)
   picture = Column(String(300))

class Category(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'category'

   id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
   name = Column(String(200), nullable = False)
   #user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
   #user = relationship(User)

class Item(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'item'

   id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
   name = Column(String(100), nullable = False)
   date = Column(DateTime, nullable = False)
   description = Column(String(300))
   price = Column(String(8))
   item_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('category.id'))
   user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
   category = relationship(Category)
   user = relationship(User)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///categoryitem.db')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

*inserting object file*:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import datetime
from database_setup import *

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///categoryitem.db')
Base.metadata.bind = engine

DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()

user1 = User(name = "a",
         email = "abc@gmail.com",
         picture = "someurl")
session.add(user1)
session.commit()

category1 = Category(name = "Books")
session.add(category1)
session.commit()

item1 = Item(name = "Da Vinci Code",
         date = datetime.datetime.now(),
         description = "2003 mystery-detective novel by Dan Brown.",
         price = "10$",
         category = category1,
         user = user1)
session.add(item1)
session.commit()
```

The error I receive on executing my Inserting file is: 
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table item has no column named date [SQL: u'INSERT INTO item (name, date, description, price, item_id, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: ('Da Vinci Code', '2017-10-26 17:42:10.172287', '2003 mystery-detective novel by Dan Brown.', '10$', 1, 1)]

Thank you for taking your time to read my code, and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: try changing the name of the `date` column. It's probably a reserved word though I'm surprised it didn't complain when you created the table in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I suspected the same and tried. Didn't work for a different column name either.

Comment: I also don't believe SQLite support true dates. You may need to pass it a formatted string. Also check your indent, it was incorrect in here but I don't know if that's a copy and paste problem or if it's in your code that way

Comment: Thank you for your help. Indentation was incorrect due to a copy-paste. Also, SQLite shouldn't be raising the error since it automatically converts it as a formatted string but stores it as a datetime object when the row is returned. Documentation: [link](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html)

Comment: Unable to duplicate.  What versions are you using?